How to convert string "1/4" into double without causing NumberFormatException in Android Studio?
I'm taking an EditText input from user like "1/3","1/4" etc. This input must be converted to Double.
This is what I'm trying to do with the code:
double shareDouble= Double.parseDouble(etShare.getText().toString());

But this throws a NumberFormatException. What I'm doing wrong. Please help..

Have you checked my answer below ?

Yes. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much.

Check below function
private double convertFractionToDouble(String fraction) throws Exception {
    String[] parts = fraction.split("/");
    if (parts.length != 2) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid fraction format");
    }
    int numerator = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int denominator = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    return (double) numerator / denominator;
}

You have to split string to index 0 and index 1.

And call it in your code like :
EditText editTextFraction = findViewById(R.id.editTextFraction);
Button buttonConvert = findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
TextView textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String fraction = editTextFraction.getText().toString().trim();

        if (fraction.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a fraction", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            double result = convertFractionToDouble(fraction);
            textViewResult.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid fraction format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});


Split the string
val s = "1/4"
val splitString = s.split("/")
val top = splitString[0].toDouble()
val bottom = splitString[1].toDouble()
    
val number = top / bottom

